# javascript does not send post request correctly

Tags: javascript

Well I am trying to post some data to a certain site in order to g, but javascript does not seem to like me that much :(.
To perform the request I do:

```
  var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    else
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    xmlhttp.open("POST","http://(removed)/forums/en/shoutbox_comet.php",true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8");
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("X-Request","JSON");
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Cookie",document.cookie); 
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)
    alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
    var channels = ['english_486', 'english_0', 'english_459','english_293','english_1310','english_292','english_459','english_293','english_970'];
    var channel = channels[Math.floor(Math.random() * channels.length)];
    var data = "channel="+channel+"&action=publish&type=message&data=HelloWorld";
    xmlhttp.send(data);
```

which sends this:

```
OPTIONS http://(removed)/forums/en/shoutbox_comet.php HTTP/1.1
Host: (removed)
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Origin: http://(removed)
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: x-request
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

how can I fix this?
I want it to send:

```
POST http://(removed)/forums/en/shoutbox_comet.php HTTP/1.1
Host: (removed)
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0
Accept: application/json
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
X-Request: JSON
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
Referer: http://(removed)/forums/en/shoutbox_comet_standalone.php?f=293&style=popout
Content-Length: 55
Cookie: (removed)
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache

channel=english_293&action=publish&type=message&data=HelloWorld
```

Comment: Is your JS running on the same domain as `http://(removed)/forums/en/shoutbox_comet.php`? If it's on a different domain then browsers will send a CORS preflight OPTIONS request before your actual POST.

Comment: _"how can I fix this?"_ What's the exact issue?

Comment: It is done via a external script, @SergiuParaschiv.

Comment: Where is the request going? AJAX calls are subject to the [same-origin-policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). That means you can't make an AJAX request from siteA to siteB.

Comment: @j08691 I want it to send the request with the data & receive the correct response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making a request to a different domain. That's a security concern for the browser. Enter [CORS](http://enable-cors.org/). The browser sends an OPTIONS request (sometimes called a 'preflight' request) before the POST to find out if the server is OK with responding to it.

You'll have to make sure your server correctly respons to these requests.

Comment: ...and depending on the response from the target server, the request may or may not be allowed to continue.

Comment: But, if I remove the following [xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("X-Request","JSON");] it will send the request as POST(without the two required headers that I need to use)
edit:
and I do not have access to the server's code, so I would be unable to edit it.

Comment: Yeah, that's one way of forcing the browser to 'forget' the fact that it's dealing with a cross-domain request, though the server, depending on implementation, could not like that.